# Limit distribution of a stochastic process (Central ;Limit Theorem)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, central-limit-theorem

Suppose we have a stochastic linear process:

$$x_{k+1} = Ax_{k} + Bw_{k} \qquad \text{with} \qquad x_{0} = a\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$$

Here, $A,B$ are known matrices and $a$ is a known vector. Moreover, the eigenvalues of $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are in the open unit disk. Finally, the elements of the sequence $\{w_{k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ are iid random variables uniformly distributed on the $m$-dimensional unit cube.

1. What would be the distribution of $x_{k}$ as $k\to\infty$?

It is a bell-shaped distribution, but for sure it is not Gaussian as it must have a compact
support---due to the fact that $w_{k}$ are compactly supported and the eigenvalues of $A$ are
in the open unit disk.

2. As an example, lets take a scalar system with $A,B = 1/2$, and $x_0 = 0$. For $k=0$, $x_0$ has a dirac distribution. For $k=1$, we have a uniform distribution supported on $[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$. For $k=2$ we would get some trapezoidal distribution supported on $[-\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4}]$. For each $k$, the distribution of $x_{k}$ is some piecewise polynomial function compactly supported which indeed looks increasingly bell-shaped. Even for this case, I can't really figure out what the limit distribution would be.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:

The linear recursion can indeed be arranged as:

$$ x_{N} = \sum^{N-1}_{k=0} A^{k}Bw_{N-k-1}$$

with $w_{k}$ being, for $k\in\{0,\ldots,N-1\}$, being independent and identically uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]^{m}$.
Thus, for $x_{N}$ with $N\to\infty$ we are looking at some form of the
central limit theorem, where $x_{\infty}$ can not possibly be normally distributed. As a plus I would like to know if the family of distributions generated by the sum for each $N$ has some sort of name (the first is a multidimensional trapezoidal distribution, the second is piecewise cuadratic, then piecewise cubic,...).

Thanks again in advance.

Comment: What is $m$, and how does it relate to $n$? Needs a definition

Comment: @unseen_rider $m$ is the dimension of the space where the elements of the sequence {} of random variables take value and it is unrelated to $n$. That is, each $w_{k}$ is uniformly distributed over the hyperbox $[−1,1]^{m}$. In the example of point 2, it happens that $n=m=1$.

Comment: Have you tried looking for an explicit solution of $x_k$? Usually these linear equations are solvable.

Comment: @A.Pesare as a linear recursion, I can express $x_N$ as a function of $w_{0},w_{1},\ldots,w_{N-1}$ (see edit). For each $N\in\mathbb{N}$, $x_N$ is the sum of $N$ (linearly transformed) uniform random variables. What I am asking is what would be limit distribution (the distribution of $x_{N}$ as $N\to\infty$.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://cse.lab.imtlucca.it/~bemporad/teaching/ac/pdf/04a-TD_sys.pdf).

Comment: @A.Pesare thanks for the link, I am familiar with control systems. Indeed, what I wrote is an asymptotically stable discrete-time linear system. Since the system is asymptotically stable, I know that the support of the limit distribution converges to a compact (and convex) set (hence the limit distribution can not possibly be normal). But beyond that I don't see how the link helps. Could you perhaps clarify?.

Comment: Sorry, the link was only a help to find the explicit expression of $x_N$, but I see that you wrote it in the EDIT.